# Mobile menu button jumping around

Tags: css, positioning

I am building a website for my church,
https://new.churchindenver.org/

and I have a mobile "Menu" button that opens the mobile menu, and a "Close" button that closes it.

Both have the following CSS:

```
display: inline;
position: absolute;
top:10px;
right: 10px;
```

I want the menu button to be in absolute position
    top:10px;
    right: 10px;

When the screen width is 601-895px it works fine. When the screen width is <=600px, the css is being ignored and the "Menu" button jumps down about 50px. (and the logo jumps down too, incidentally, though not as far) Does anyone have any idea why?

Thanks!

Whether ! important or not, and no matter what I put there, the menu button (and the logo) are in absolute position, but apparently not to their parent element.

UPDATE:
Based on Elraphty's suggestion, I made the following hack, which seems to fix it. I'm still not sure what's going on, but at least it looks right. I put:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #menu {
        top: -41px ! important;
    }
    #logo {
        top: -10px ! important;
    }
}
```

and now the menu button and logo are in their proper position at top 10px.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: Thanks Charlie. I edited my question to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by

```
    top:10px;
    right: 10px;
```

Since they both have absolute positions, the solution write a media query than changes the top and right values when the screen is lesser than 600px e.g

```
     @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        . class {        
            top: 5px ! important;
            right: 5px  ! important;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure I understand the reasoning for that. I put that in and it does not change anything.

Comment: Whether ! important or not, and no matter what I put there, the menu button (and the logo) are in absolute position, but apparently not to their parent element. What you suggested, though, gave me the idea for how to fix it. This is a hack, and I don't know why I have to do it, but it's working.

Comment: Make the nav position relative, so since the logo and button have absolute positions, they should be position ed  in the relative navbar, not the body itself

Comment: Putting the #menu button in relative position makes it jump to the left edge (instead of right:10px;), and it jumps back down another 42px lower than it's supposed to be. I believe top: and right: only work with absolute positioning.

Comment: Setting #menu to have { top: -41px ! important; } works as a hack to correct the 51px offset. I'd prefer to understand why the absolute positioning is being ignored, but I can live with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
.nav {
     position: relative
 }

 .navItems {
       display: inline;
      position: absolute;
       top:10px;
      right: 10px;
 }
```

So the items are positioned absolute in the nav element not the body element

Or use flex

```
.nav {
     height: 100px;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: center;
 }
```

Comment: Setting #nav to have relative position does not change anything. As mentioned in the original post, the nav items #menu and #logo are already displayed inline in absolute position.

Comment: Using flex for the #nav also does not change anything. The #menu and #logo still are ignoring their absolute positioning.